How to get the epoch time in eastern time?
How do I get the time in seconds since epoch of a python datetime in eastern time?
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

et_tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')

initial_start_dt =  et_tz.localize(datetime(2024, 8, 24, 4, 0, 0)).astimezone(et_tz)
initial_end_dt =  et_tz.localize(datetime(2024, 8, 24, 5, 0, 0)).astimezone(et_tz)

This question Convert python datetime to epoch with strftime does not take into account the timezone.

Please include a [mre] (which requires both the input and desired result)

These don't answer my question. This is an MRE.  What is wrong with current contributors to SO?

@BAR As Mat said, an MRE needs to include input and desired output

Why did you use both localize and astimezone with the same time zone?  If you used a UTC time zone with astimezone you might have had some luck.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp

your system time zone is not set to UTC, you can obtain the POSIX timestamp by supplying tzinfo=timezone.utc

timestamp = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp(). Also datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
